# Unity Game Not working even after building

Tags: c#, windows, build, unity-game-engine

My game is not working even after successfully building in the PC, Mac standalone.
I tried to build it both in 32 bit and 64 bit but the .exe is still not opening. The game is running in unity but not after building it. I've also tried to change the compatibility settings in the properties but nothing works. 
Here's the Game link:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7LawZAwfUJUUXNyU3hXS3ByQTQ
Here's My output_log.txt:

```
Mono path[0] = 'H:/Projects/Unity/FirstOne/Final/Roll A Ball ;)_Data/Managed'
Mono path[1] = 'H:/Projects/Unity/FirstOne/Final/Roll A Ball ;)_Data/Mono'
Mono config path = 'H:/Projects/Unity/FirstOne/Final/Roll A Ball ;)_Data/Mono/etc'
PlayerConnection initialized from H:/Projects/Unity/FirstOne/Final/Roll A Ball ;)_Data (debug = 0)
PlayerConnection initialized network socket : 0.0.0.0 55357
Multi-casting "[IP] 192.168.1.110 [Port] 55357 [Flags] 3 [Guid] 3232448567 [EditorId] 4073115951 [Version] 1048832 [Id] WindowsPlayer(Aashish-PC) [Debug] 1" to [225.0.0.222:54997]...
Waiting for connection from host on [0.0.0.0:55357]...
PlayerConnection accepted from [192.168.1.110] handle:0x344
Started listening to [0.0.0.0:55357]
Using monoOptions --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,embedding=1,defer=y,address=0.0.0.0:56567
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you build your game you get a folder called YourGame_Data, inside there's an `output_log.txt`. Look for logs or errors there to debug your build.

Edit: It seems in the end, the problem was the `;)` in the game name.

Comment: There was no such file, i checked into other folders within that folder also.

Comment: What version of Unity? Is this the Mac or PC build?

Comment: Unity 5.5.1f and PC Build

Comment: Check the game link i've Shared

Comment: Yes, I checked. Can you try to go to Edit-->Project Settings-->Player and check 'Use Player Log'. According to this link, it should help: https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/cannot-find-output_log-txt-log-file-not-generated.174939/

Comment: When you built it, did you check the "Debug build"? I normally don't but I get the log-file...

Comment: I'd suggest updating to latest unity and make sure you have the correct Build-settings checked when installning.

Comment: Check my output_log

Comment: Oh, you found it! What did you do to make it appear?

Comment: I checked the "Script Debugging" option while building.

Comment: Well there doesn't seem to be any crashes in the output_log.txt... The only thing I can think of right now would be if the ";)" is causing any problems somehow.

Comment: Have you tried this: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1101721/built-unity-game-wont-launch.html

Comment: Whoa Thank you so much buddy that ';)' was a big problem ......Next time i swear i'll not try to be this much cool.

Comment: Nice! Good to know! Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

When you build the .exe , it comes with a data folder for .exe to use. They need to be in the same folder.

Also someone says [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1101721/built-unity-game-wont-launch.html) looks like the same problem

> So i fixed the problem. Now the Built game started immediatly.
>
> I Unticked "Display Resolution Dialog".
>
> And after, built the game two times to make sure it was the problem. And it was

Also can you add more details like;

-Does it give an error code?

-Does it stuck in loading screen?

Comment: Nothing Happens when i click on the .exe file